# C++ equal-operator on std::divides

Tags: c++, divide

I have a question about the equal-operator.
Can this operator in any way be used on the std::divides?

My current code is like that:

```
template<typename TItor, typename TStream, typename TPred>
void CalcUp_copy(TItor begin, TItor end, TStream& stream, TPred pred)
{
    if (!stream.good())
    {
        throw std::string
        {
            cStreamError
        };
    }

    TItor prevItor = begin;
    TItor itor = begin;

    while (std::distance(begin, end) > 1)
    {
        while (itor != end)
        {
            prevItor = itor;
            itor++;
        }

        stream << pred(*begin, *prevItor) << " ";

        end = prevItor;
        begin++;
        prevItor = begin;
        itor = begin;
    }
}
```

Now the goal is, that you can use following predicates: plus, minus, divides, multiplies;
Now divides will make problems when there is a division by zero.

Is there any way I can solve this in a way like:

```
if (pred == std::divides<TItor::value_type> && *prevItor == 0)
{
    throw std::string
    {
        cDivideZeroError
    };
}
```

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: don't do this, what if someday you switch to a lambda expression? (although I ***guess*** all `divides` should compare equal)

Comment: btw why it's call `pred`?

Comment: @appleapple, `pred` is short for `predicate`.

Comment: You could use `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<TPred, std::divides<TItor::value_type>>)`, but as @appleapple mentioned, that would break if you switch to lambdas, your own operator structs, or anything that isn't *exactly* `std::divides`.

Comment: This for a university assignment and we gotta do it like that.
I know that this is not in any way perfectly correct.
But for know I just have to know if I can somehow know if there is a divides given to the function

Comment: They _probably_ want you to specialise

Comment: Those are not predicates – predicates are truth-valued functions.

Comment: @chris those are not predicates, like @ molbdnilo said.

Comment: oh, you cannot compare non `divide` to `divide`, sorry for misleading. (re my first comment)

Comment: @appleapple, Right, but I'm 99% sure that's why it's called `pred`. A misunderstanding there is reasonable.

Comment: @chris thanks for provide the information anyway. yes I know it probably mean predicate, I was meant to say OP maybe choose the wrong name.